# Jenkins Pipeline - Start a stage 2 hours after the 1st one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

In a declarative pipeline parallel block, it is possible to specify 2nd stage to start with a lag of 2 hours after the first one has started?

Let's say I have 2 stages as below:

```
parallel {
    stage('A') {
        steps {
            script {
                sh do something
            }
        }
    }
    stage('B') {
        steps {
            script {
                sh do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the job is kicked off, stage A starts. 2 hours later, Stage B would start. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need to sop for 2 hours? If stage B needs some of the results of stage A, it would mean they depend on each other, so it could be better not to make them parallel.

Comment: They aren't dependant on each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "sleep" within a stage to pause its execution.

```
stage("B") {
    steps {
        echo "Pausing stage B"
        sleep(time: 2, unit: "HOURS")
    }
}
```